# Interface indexed signature with union types (string and function)

Tags: typescript

There is a problem with calling these indexed types from `IFoo`. The code is working in console but TS compiler throw errors.

Note that I don't want touch calls `Bar[Foo.A]` and `Bar[Foo.A1(1)]` and consts `Foo` and `Bar`. I need TS side solution.

You can check below code on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=28#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOygXigCgB4C4oLgWwCMIAnAShQD4oBnYEgSwQHMAoVp4UgMwEMBjaAEkYAe1FQA3qyhQA2gGsIIHHUYsAuqvpNmUAD6xErAL7tOPAcIBCvElJnylK2js3b1bM636iEdWHEcEXEUB1kAQRwAcgjogBpHCIBGHEwcPCJSCmRqAAMIgBJJDBM803Zff2AoWxJgurDpSJjGwhAoZyg4xNlY5OjWuyh2zuVugYqfPxpRABsIADo50WY0OrkxUUWIjTJp-3mllbWNrZ3ktGSyPaA).

```js
type Fun = (x: number) => string

interface IFoo {
  [key: string]: string | Fun
}

interface IBar {
  [key: string]: string
}

const Foo: IFoo = {
  A: 'A',
  A1: (x: number) => `A${x}`
}

const Bar: IBar = {
  A: 'Bar by key A',
  'A1': 'Bar by key A1'
}

console.log(Bar[Foo.A])
console.log(Bar[Foo.A1(1)])
```

Problems:

1. `Bar[Foo.A]`:

   ```
   Type 'Fun' cannot be used as an index type.
   ```
2. `Bar[Foo.A1(1)]`:

   ```
   This expression is not callable.
   Not all constituents of type 'string | Fun' are callable.
   Type 'string' has no call signatures.
   ```

Comment: The solution is as simple as removing type from `const Foo: IFoo` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE5WQbwFDLIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC61dDIjeAvnnggHsQdZADEBA5AF5cBZAEFqAcnlKANHPkBGagAoAHtRABXALYAjaAEppAPmQADeQBIc+7g559BwsMkxQ1BhY0rKEishKAcjm5MhkcaoahCpaSsrRsfEUCmle-EI0AgA2EAB0xQKMugFE4gJl8sxWBcIl5ZXVtfWNWrpaVs14QA

Comment: @AlekseyL. it is not a solution. I might as well change `type Fun` to `type Fun = any`. But I need correct TS solution.

Comment:  typing it as you did is pretty close to typing with `any` (you're widening the type of variable to something more general than typescript can infer on its own). What do you call _correct TS solution_?